# Does PCA change the values of the data?

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction, pca

Principal Component Analysis is a means to reduce the dimensionality of data, if I understand correctly.

So if I have a 1000 sample point 12 dimensional matrix and reduce it to a 1000 sample point 2 dimensional one, then are the values of the sample points themselves changed in some way? or are simply 10 dimensions/columns thrown out and 2 of the original remain?

Comment: Welcome to DataScience.SE! You are running into the difference between [feature _selection_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) (selecting a subset of the original features) and [feature _extraction_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_extraction) (deriving new ones).

Comment: Glad to be here! So PCA falls into feature selection right? Because feature extraction varies from field by field,application to application, if I'm not wrong?

Comment: No, feature extraction, because the principal components returned by PCA are _functions_ of the input features, not usually a subset of them. I think this will become more clear if you apply PCA to some data and see what the principal components are.

Comment: @Emre Ok. So PCA is feaure extraction? Wow, I guess you learn something new everyday!

Comment: Related: [Does dimension reduction always lose some information?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66060/does-dimension-reduction-always-lose-some-information)

Comment: Related: [Choosing number of principal components to retain](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44060/choosing-number-of-principal-components-to-retain)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the new 2 dimensional values will be a projection of original 12 dimensional points onto the two principle components (vectors).

please refer to the first figure in this clear tutorial:
http://lazyprogrammer.me/tutorial-principal-components-analysis-pca/

Comment: I have a bad habit, but I like to confirm things, so you're saying PCA does in fact changes values of data right? Does this ever cause any significant loss ever?

Comment: Of course it can cause significant loss. Any dimensionality reduction can cause loss, or we would always reduce data to 0 dimensions.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse if we did that then there would be no data to learn from, and reducing too many dimensions may lead to subsequent overfitting.

Comment: Therefore, every dimensionality reduction will be lossy at some point (or not reduce dimensionality anymore). Proof complete.

Answer (score 1):

PCA is a **transform:** it creates new (transformed) features from the original data. In general if you choose fewer dimensions (e.g. you chose to reduce m=12 -> n=2 dimensions), it's lossy and will throw away some of in the information content of the original data. **The higher n is, the less you lose, and for m=n, you preserve all the original information** (although you still do a vector transform on the data, so the extracted features are != the original data).

It was your (arbitrary) decision to choose the parameter n=2 (number of Principal Components), you could try other values or explore a range. You could have chosen n=5, n=9, or even the maximum possible: n=12.

For **standard rules-of-thumb on how to choose n, see e.g.
[Choosing number of principal components to retain](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44060/choosing-number-of-principal-components-to-retain)**

> (Scree plot, Proportion of total variance explained, Average eigenvalue rule, Log-eigenvalue diagram, etc.)

where a Scree Plot is a simple line-segment plot that shows the fraction of total variance in the data as explained or represented by each PC. Usually the scree plot will have a knee where the number of PCs explains most of the variance, and if so that might suggest you an upper bound on n.

There are other rules-of-thumb discussed there too.
You can find tons of articles on this subject.

See also e.g. [How many principal components to take?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067446/how-many-principal-components-to-take)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. PCA changes the values of the data. It transforms the data and projects it into a new dimension.

This video is good to learn about [PCA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPmV3j1dAv4#action=share)

Answer (score 0):

PCA is used to find the variables that contain the most information, and to remove the ones that have little information or sometimes just noise.

If only 2 dimensions out of the initial 10 dimensions carry the most information, then only those 2 dimensions need to be used. Hence the PCA has helped in reducing the dataset's dimensions.